# Java - How to make a program run until a specific value is entered

Tags: java, loops

I need to make a program that will continue to run and accept numbers as inputs until "0" is entered and then the program will stop.

I believe I need it to be a while loop; Here is what I have so far.

```
do{
   if(yourInput > 0) {
   }
   else if(yourInput < 0) {
   }
}while(yourInput !=0);
```

If I input anything other than 0, it will just print out the same integer a million times.... what am I missing? I need another loop. How do I phrase the new loop so it will keep accepting entries unless "0" is entered.

Comment: Receive the input inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the scanner...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
do{
   int yourInput = scanner.nextInt();
   if(yourInput > 0) {
   }
   else if(yourInput < 0) {
   }
}while(yourInput !=0);
```